# SQLPLUS session to remember history

Tags: perl, sqlplus

I have just started using sqlplus for oracle and it is horrible, I was trying to look for ideas if anyone has any scripts written around sqlplus which stores history and and it works more like an editor.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using YASQL, http://sourceforge.net/projects/yasql/, which is an alternative client written in Perl.

It is pretty neat and covers most of what one would expect from a DB CLI client.  It does not support everything `sqlplus` does, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the extremely handy [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) command.  It will wrap almost any command and add [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)-style command history and editing.  It supports, colors, custom completions, and [all that jazz](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/rlwrap.html).  I'm not sure if the link I provided to `rlwrap` is the "official" source, and compiling it can sometimes be a pain, but your favorite Unix package source should have some version of it available.